# Intellisense not picking up my table variable correctly

Tags: visual-studio, ide, intellisense, axapta, dynamics-365-operations

Anyone know how I can make intellisense in the editor to show my table variable myTable?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intellisense is extremely slow at picking up the source. Wait a couple minutes, it will likely work then. That is why oldtimers like me rely on copy/paste, Ctrl-C, Ctrl-V.